# UiBarButtonItem Same Color as "Done" Button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uicolor

I want to be able to programatically add a `UIBarButtonItem` to a Navigation Bar and set it's tint color to the exact same blue shade as Apple's "Done" `UIBarButtonItem`.

I am already doing this for Apple's red shade in this block of code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myDeleteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(myDeleteItemsMethod:)];
myDeleteButton.tintcolor = [[UIColor alloc] initwithRed:1 green:0.0470275 blue:0.0116515 alpha:1];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myDeleteButton;
```

I guess all I need are the RGB values.

I'm having a hard time trying to "reverse engineer" a `UIBarButtonItem's` tint that was made in Storyboard (Can't cast `UIColor` as text).

And I also realize that Xcode's color palette has an area for "developer" color schemes but it does not appear to include the color for the "Done" button.

Comment: This is just a UX/UI Suggestion but if the button you're trying to make blue is actually a delete/clear button it shouldn't be the same color blue anyway. That blue is reserved for finishing something not canceling it. Delete/clear buttons should be a shade of red in most instances.

Just food for thought.

Comment: Mostly agree with Ryan for this case, but for posterity: I believe red is usually reserved for data loss. That'd only apply to a cancel button if you've entered data.

Comment: Eh, I didn't give the best example. The purpose of my example was just to show that I can assign a color: red. I just need to assign Apple's standard blue

Comment: myDeleteButton.tintcolor should be myDeleteButton.tintColor
Xcode will catch and suggest fix but just fyi. :)

Answer (score 14):

I spent about 15 mins with my DigitalColor Meter and basically guessed and checked until I finally got it. The problem is that you're adding a "tint" to a black button to make it blue, so it won't be the right blue. Here's the correct measurements:

```
[buttonName setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:34.0/255.0 green:97.0/255.0 blue:221.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 8):

You want `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone` rather than `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered`.

Comment: My snippet of code above was just an example of how I assign the color "red". I'm trying to imitate the "done" button by using it's color

Comment: Yes, and to get the exact colour, you must use the "done" style. It's not reproducible with a tint colour.

Comment: For those using Interface Builder you can also use the Style drop down and select "Done".

Comment: -1, Reason: `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone` does NOT set a color. This asker is trying to match the "blue" color of the default `UINavigationBar`'s `UIBarButtonItem` "blue" color. The correct answer is below by user1641653, which is a close color with RGB.

Comment: @JRG-Developer: He wants it to look like a Done button. That means using `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone`. Good job.

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem * myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Blue Button" style:` **UIBarButtonItemStyleDone** `target:self action:@selector(actionSend:)];` is guaranteed to work even if Apple changes the [Done] colors.

Comment: @gothicdev Which is exactly why one ought to use it in this scenario.

Answer (score 5):

The proposed color of user1641653 is just the bottom color of the real DoneButton taken with the color meter. The problem is that the shadow of a plain/borderer button is different than the one of a SystemButton. The shadow will change the proposed color by -11, -36, -11.
So if you really want it to look like the real DoneButton you have to add those values to the proposed 34/97/221.

This means:

```
[yourButton setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:45.0/255.0 green:133.0/255.0 blue:232.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
```

Comment: This is much closer than user1641653's color! Thank you for your answer.